# @Html.DropDownList issue in razor view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form that respond to a submit button.

I have my drop down list on menu as following:

```
@Html.DropDownList("State", new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Please select" }, 
    new SelectListItem { Value = "AL", Text="Alabama" }, ....
    new SelectListItem { Value = "WY", Text="Wyoming" })
```

How can I get the selected value as bool or preferably as string in my model ..

I need to validate

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a state.")]
public string/bool State { get; set; }
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: this is trickier than it should be. Even better you, could create this in an Action Partial. That way you can create the select list in an action methos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a model-bound helper

```
@model MVC4.Models.Model
```

and then

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.State, new List<SelectListItem>
new SelectListItem { Text = "Please select" }, 
    new SelectListItem { Value = "AL", Text="Alabama" }, ....
    new SelectListItem { Value = "WY", Text="Wyoming" })
```

Comment: I am almost certain I tried this and last time it didn't work as my other textboxfor properties are bound in the same manner .. Thanks.

Comment: consider refactoring your code further to use an @Action Partial -- Or as Darin correctly puts it 'child action'. This way you can create your selectlist in your Controller and not 'muddy' your View.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I get the selected value as bool

It hardly makes sense to bind a state name to a boolean variable.

Use string instead:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a state.")]
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

then you could have a controller:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // there was a validation error - probably the user didn't select a state
            // => redisplay the view so that he can fix the error
            return View(model);
        }

        // at this stage the model is valid
        // you could use the model.State property that will hold the selected value
        return Content("Thanks for selecting state: " + model.State);
    }
}
```

and finally you will have a corresponding strongly typed view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.State)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(
            x => x.State,
            new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Please select" }, 
                new SelectListItem { Value = "AL", Text="Alabama" },
                .....
                new SelectListItem { Value = "WY", Text="Wyoming" }
            },
            "-- select a state --"
        )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.State)
    </div>
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

Comment: O, completely missed the bool part. wouldn't it be best to create this in a Action partial?

Comment: I don't see what partials have to do with the question.

Comment: saves him the trouble of creating select list in the View. Doesn't seem right to have to create Model parts on View

Comment: And what do you think a partial is? It's a view. This country list should be populated in the controller if you want to be following best practices.

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant to say. an Action driven partial so the select list is created in the controller

Comment: By *action driven partial* do you mean child action?

Comment: Your answer works perfect, however the one before by Dave worked too and that is why I marked that as answer. ... For the bool part, Perhaps I could have parsed it as bool in my model, however, you are right,  I did preferably needed it as string :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For the "Please Select" item, you'll need to set a value of the empty string. If you don't, IIRC, the `Value` and the `Text` will be rendered the same (so your required validator thinks there is a value).

The `State` property in your model should be a `string`.

Comment: Thanks .. makes sense. I removed and used my state as default selected value. That way I don't have to worry even if they do not select any states.